# How to make Simplify (and FullSimplify) give a default output if $Assumptions are contradictory

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I have a function (deep inside my package) that looks like

```
signedPart =
  Function[{expr, inf},
    Assuming[Join[#>0&/@(Variables[expr]), {expr<0}], Simplify[Sign[inf]]]
  ]
```

This function is supposed to return the sign of the input `inf` assuming that all variables given in `expr` are (real) positive *and* `expr` is negative.

Some examples that work as intended:

```
signedPart[-x^2-y^2,x]
(*1*)

signedPart[-x^2+y^2,x-y]
(*Sign[x-y]*)
```

However, the following

```
signedPart[x^2 + y^2, -x]
```

gives a warning that the assumptions are contradictory (because `x^2 + y^2` can't be negative), and arbitrarily returns `-1`.

**Question**:  What can I do to suppress `Simplify` from issuing warning messages and instead have it return a default of `+1` if contradictory assumptions are encountered?

**What I prefer**:
For the sake of speed, I prefer a solution that is as low-level as possible.  For example, inside `Simplify` there may be a low-level function `ContradictoryAssumptionsQ` that checks for this.  If I had access to this function I would wrap my code to test and return the appropriate result.  I would prefer not to use `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, `Reduce` or `Refine` on the assumptions to test for a contradiction since these are much too general-purpose (overkill) for the task.  Also, my function `signedPart` will be used many times, so I'd like it to be fast and not issue messages.

Comment: See `Check[ ]`...

Comment: Why do you say that returning $-1$ in your last case is arbitrary? Your assumptions in that case end up including $x>0$, so $-x<0$ and the sign of $-x$ is indeed $-1$. What am I missing?

Comment: @MarcoB Well, I guess that example is not a good one.  If you try `Assuming[x < 0 && x > 0, Simplify[Sign[x]]]`, you get `1`.  It has (arbitrarily) picked the second assumption and dropped the first.

Comment: @MarcoB In general, of course, you'd expect arbitrary output to be possible. If $1<0$ then I am a fish.

Comment: Here may be a solution: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267089/how-to-use-systemprivateassumptionaccess-and-assumptions/267090

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message name is `$Assumptions::cas` so it is coming from the setting of `$Assumptions` rather than from within `Simplify`. You can confirm this with:

```
$Assumptions = x < 0 && x > 0
```

> During evaluation of In[111]:= $Assumptions::cas: Warning:
>   contradictory assumption(s) x<0&&x>0 encountered. >>

Don't forget to reset `$Assumptions` after this!

```
$Assumptions = True;
```

There don't appear to be any accessible internals behind this mechanism, so I suspect it will be difficult to find anything lower-level to shortcut it. However, as belisarius commented, you can use `Check` to detect the message and return 1.

You are interested in speed, so it will be a good idea to interrupt the evaluation as soon as possible rather than wait for `Simplify` to run -  I suggest using `Throw/Catch` for that purpose. This requires setting `$Assumptions` explicitly rather than via `Assuming` so that `Throw` can be evaluated before `Simplify`.

Finally you want to suppress the message output, so use `Quiet` to wrap the whole thing.

The finished function is:

```
signedPart = Function[{expr, inf},
  Quiet[
   Catch[
    Block[{$Assumptions},
         Check[$Assumptions = Join[# > 0 & /@ (Variables[expr]), {expr < 0}], Throw[1]];
     Simplify[Sign[inf]]]],
   $Assumptions::cas]]
```