# How to use System`Private`AssumptionAccess and Assumptions`*?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation, assumptions, undocumented, internals

I see this function is used by some symbols in `` Assumptions`* ``, and it `HasDownCode` and does not `HasDownValue`. Symbols in `` Assumptions`* `` may be bindings of it.

How to use it?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it can accept two arguments, which the first is some expression and the second is an integer from `0` to `31`.

> There are corresponding symbols in `` Assumptions` ``, who may be little different (e.g. cache some results for repeated using?) compared to those in `` System` ``.

### List the assumptions

Same to `` Assumptions`AllAssumptions ``.

```
$Assumptions = {a,b,c}
System`Private`AssumptionAccess[]
```

### 1. Test a prime

Same to `` Assumptions`APrimeQ ``.

```
System`Private`AssumptionAccess[Prime@50, 1]
System`Private`AssumptionAccess[1+Prime@50, 1]
```

### 5.

Same to `` Assumptions`AAlgebraicQ ``.

### 25. Add an assumption if compatible

Same to `` Assumptions`AssumeTrue ``.

```
$Assumptions = {a,b,c}
System`Private`AssumptionAccess[c==1, 25]
$Assumptions
```

### 28. Add an assumption no matter whether compatible

Same to `` Assumptions`AddAssumption ``.

```
$Assumptions = {a,b,c}
System`Private`AssumptionAccess[d, 28]
$Assumptions
```

```
$Assumptions = {a,b,c}
System`Private`AssumptionAccess[c==1, 28]
$Assumptions
```